# Simplest thread-safe message passing in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I’ve been thinking about the simplest possible (and thus fastest) way to pass a message between two processes. So we have a producer thread and a consumer thread and they both hold a reference to the message passer. My current thinking for how this could work (where producer blocks until consumer has picked up the last message¹) is:²

```java
class MessagePasser<T> {
  enum MessagePasserState { SENT, RECEIVED }

  private MessagePasserState state = RECEIVED;
  private T message;

  public void send(T message) {
     while (state == SENT) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
     }
     this.message = message;
     state = SENT;
  }

  public T receive() {
     while (state == RECEIVED) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
     }
     T message = this.message;
     state = SENT;
     return message;
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn’t work if more than one thread is accessing `send()` or `receive()` (is there any way to enforce that?³) but are there any other flaws in this approach?

---

1. I’m thinking that if this works, adding buffering should be simple.
2. Apologies for any typos, errors in the code: I’m writing this in the browser.
3. I wonder how this would work in other languages as well—e.g., C, C++, Rust, etc. I imagine this approach would be impossible in Rust, but there might be a way to pass ownership of the message holder between threads that would be neater.

Comment: The [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) has a simple solution.  You code probably 'works' if you make the state volatile for visibility, but the performance won't be good with those sleep calls, and in any case as you say you ought to guard against parallel execution, in which case, wait on the monitor, not sleep.  But I'd just use the semaphores.

Comment: Does “two processes” mean two programs, or two workflows within the same program?

Comment: In this instance it would be two threads within the same program. It looks like what I wrote above is equivalent to the Lamport fixed-size buffer  for a buffer size of 1 (but with a sleep in the loop instead of a tight loop, I added the sleeps so that the thread scheduler wouldn’t waste time on a tight loop). As long as there is only one producer and one consumer there should be no contention.